# how to regex a value of a specific key in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string with key values in this format:

```
"info":"infotext","day":"today","12":"here","info":"infotext2","info":"infotext3"
```

I want to get the value (=infotexts) of all "info" keys. How can this be done?

Comment: This data looks like your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433581/how-to-parse-json-in-python) - Are you now trying to parse that data without `json` - if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your `infotext` does not contain (escaped) quotes, you could try something like this:

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'"info":"([^"]+)', str)
>>> m
['infotext', 'infotext2', 'infotext3']
```

We simply match `"info":"` and then as many non-`"` characters as possible (which are captured and thus returned).

Answer (score 4):

Use the json, Luke

```
s = '"info":"infotext","day":"today","12":"here","info":"infotext2","info":"infotext3"'

import json

def pairs_hook(pairs):
    return [val for key, val in pairs if key == 'info']

p = json.loads('{' + s + '}', object_pairs_hook=pairs_hook)
print p # [u'infotext', u'infotext2', u'infotext3']
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json):

> object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of object_pairs_hook will be used instead of the dict.

Just for the sake of completeness, here's a regular expression that does the same:

```
rg = r'''(?x)

    "info"
    \s* : \s*
    "
        (
            (?:\\.|[^"])*
        )
    "
'''
re.findall(rg, s) # ['infotext', 'infotext2', 'infotext3']
```

This also handles spaces around `:` and escaped quotes inside strings, like e.g.

```
 "info"  :   "some \"interesting\" information"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<="info":")(.+?)(?=")`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [140]: import re

In [141]: strs='''"info":"infotext","day":"today","12":"here","info":"infotext2","info":"infotext3"'''

In [146]: [x.split(":")[-1].strip('"') for x in  re.findall(r'"info":"\w+"',strs)]
Out[146]: ['infotext', 'infotext2', 'infotext3']
```